# Pulp Lp : can't reach variables

Tags: python, pulp

I'm building a lp with Python Pulp :

```
   # Import the PuLP lib
    from pulp import *

    # Products list
    products = ["car", "cycle"]

    profit = {"car": 8, "cycle": 12}

    uses  = {
            "Plastic":      [2.0, 4.0],
            "Wood":         [1.0, 1.0],
            "Steel":        [1.0, 2.0]
    }

    # Problem variables 
    x = LpVariable.dicts("products ", products , 0)

    # Maximise profit
    prob += lpSum([profit[i] * x[i] for i in products ]), "Maximise" // This is working

    prob += lpSum([uses[0][i] * x[i] for i in  products]) <= 142 ,"MaxPlasticStock" // This is not working



     prob.solve()
```

This is the error about my last for loop MaxPlasticStock constraint:

```
KeyError: 0
```

I also can't print : (products[x]) or use any LP variable like this x[0], I find this being strange :

```
KeyError: 0.
```

Another error, I can't call any of my decisions variables, trying to call "cycle" :

```
 prob += x[1] * 5 <= 142 ,"MaxPlasticStock"
```

gives :

```
KeyError: 1
```

If I change my last line like this, the lp runs fine ( but the constraint doesnt work, of course):

```
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in  products]) <= 142 ,"MaxPlasticStock"
```

Do you have any idea on how to use the uses object, for my constraints ?

**Edit :** **Please don't bother, I 'm changing the lp like this :**

```
plasticAmount =  {car : 2.0, cycle : 4.0 }

prob += lpSum([plasticAmount[i] * x[i] for i in  products]) <= 142 ,"MaxPlasticStock"
```

It is longer and I have to separates things, but at least, it works .

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: `uses` is a dict so you need to use one of its key to access the lists of values it contains : `Plastic`, `Wood` or `Steel`

Comment: how can i call x[0]

Comment: you can't. in your code `x` is indexed by the list `products`. so element `x[0]` does not exist. you would instead need to look for element `x["car"]`. which you could also call `x[products[0]]`